# How to update a MS Access database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi I'm having trouble with updating one of my tables using vb.net when i click on the button to update the data base it give me the error "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters."
here is the code

```
Protected Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim aConnection As New OleDbConnection
    Dim aCommand As New OleDbCommand
    Dim SQLQuery, aConnectionString As String
    Dim Text As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim aDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim aDataReader As New DataSet
    SQLQuery = "Update Review Set report='Yes' Where Text='" & Text & "'"
    aConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data/BookReviewWebsite.accdb")
    aConnection = New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
    aConnection.Open()

    aCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQLQuery, aConnection)

    aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


    Label15.Text = "Review has been reported"

    aConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Review, Report and Text`. Here you have two fields and a table name, you should check if your database effectively contains a table named `Review` and if, in this table, there are two field named `report` and `Text`.

If your really have this table and these fields, then you need to enclose the word `TEXT` with square brackets because the word TEXT is a reserved keyword in Access 2007.

Last, but not least of your problems is the query string itself. Concatenating strings in that way could be a source of errors. If you have a single quote in your 'Text' variable then the results could be impredictable and range from Syntax error  to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

```
SQLQuery = "Update Review Set report='Yes' Where [Text]=?"
aCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQLQuery, aConnection)
aCommand.Parameter.AddWithValue("@p1", Text)
aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```